# Multiline shebang in OCaml?

Tags: shell, ocaml, comments, multiline, shebang

In short, I'd like to abstract this shebang so I can literally copy and paste it into other .ML files without having to specify the filename each time:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ocamlscript -o hello

print_endline "Hello World!"
```

I realize I could just drop the `-o hello` bit, but I'd like all the binaries to have UNIX names (`hello`), instead of Windows names (`hello.ml.exe`).

You need a complex shebang to do this. A Clojure example that has the desired behavior:

```
":";exec clj -m `basename $0 .clj` $0 ${1+"$@"}
":";exit
```

Clojure is Java-based, which is why `clj` needs the basename of the file (`something`, not `something.clj`). In order to get the basename, you need a multiline shebang, because a single line shebang can only handle a single, simple, static command line argument. In order to do multiline shebangs, you need a syntax which simultaneously:

- Sends shell commands to the shell
- Hides the shell commands from the main language

Does anyone know of OCaml trickery to do this? I've tried the following with no success:

```
(*
exec ocamlscript -o `basename $0 .ml` $0 ${1+"$@"}
exit
*)

let rec main = print_endline "Hello World!"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're looking for is a shell and Objective Caml polyglot (where the shell part invokes an ocaml interpreter to perform the real work). Here's a relatively simple one. Adapt to use `ocamlscript` if necessary, though I don't see the point.

```
#!/bin/sh
"true" = let exec _ _ _ = "-*-ocaml-*- vim:set syntax=ocaml: " in
exec "ocaml" "$0" "$@"
;;
(* OCaml code proper starts here *)
print_endline "hello"
```

Comment: The point is to send the filename, sans the ".ml" file extension, to `ocamlscript -o`, so that any binaries created don't end in ".ml".

Comment: can't you rename it after the binary is created? Good luck!

Comment: @shellter I could with a Makefile, but for scripting purposes I'd prefer to just call `./myscript.ml`.

Comment: @Gilles Thanks so much! I swapped `ocamlscript` for just the `ocaml` interpreter, and this shebang works like a charm for both interpreted and compiled modes.

Comment: Quite clever, I love this.

Answer (score 3):

After some trials, I found this shebang:

```
#!/bin/sh
"true" = let x' = "" in (*'
    sh script here
*) x'
```

It is sort of an improvement of Gilles’ proposal, as it permits to write a full shell script inside the OCaml comment, without being bothered at all with syntax incompatibilities.

The script must terminate (eg. with `exec` or `exit`) without reaching the end of the comment, otherwise a syntax error will occur. This can be fixed easily, but it is not very useful regarding the intended use of such a trick.

Here is a variant that entails zero runtime overhead on the OCaml side, but declares a new type name (choose it arbitrarily complicated if this is bothering):

```
#!/bin/sh
type int' (*' >&- 2>&-
    sh script here
*)
```

For example, here is a script that executes the OCaml code with modules Str and Unix, and can also compile it when passed the parameter `--compile`:

```
#!/bin/sh
type int' (*' >&- 2>&-
    if [ "$1" = "--compile" ]; then
        name="${0%.ml}"
        ocamlopt -pp 'sed "1s/^#\!.*//"' \
          str.cmxa unix.cmxa "$name.ml" -o "$name" \
          || exit
        rm "$name".{cm*,o}
        exit
    else
        exec ocaml str.cma unix.cma "$0" "$@"
    fi
*)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that ocamlscript supports this.  It may be worth submitting a feature request to the author to allow customization of the compiled binary's extension without specifying the full output basename.

Comment: Will do. In the mean time, I would like a workaround using shebang hacks.